# iOS - Blocking Content while keyword is not in the url

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, ios9, ios-extensions

Is it possible to use the iOS content blocking exstension to block specific content even though the keyword isnt in the url?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible you may block any content of website which is open in safari 
for this we use selector key word. This is use html tag id or class then apply rules. for example

you want block comment box and box div class is "comment_box".

```
{"trigger": {"url-filter": ".*"},"action": {"type": "css-display-none","selector":".comments_box"}}
```

for class we use . (dot) and for id we use # .